# How to trigger Cloud Functions when new project is created in org?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I am working on a script that will need to be triggered when a new project has been created in the GCP org, however I simply cannot find where newly created projects are listed (Checked Stackdriver logs but couldn't find anything at the org level), wondering if there is any other way to trigger Cloud Functions when a new project has been created?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an [Aggregated Sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks) which publish a message to a Pub/Sub topic (which can trigger a Cloud Function).

This is how I put a message into a Pub/Sub topic after a project creation:

```
export PROJECT_ID=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID_WHICH_WILL_HOST_PUBSUB_TOPIC]
export ORGANIZATION_ID=[YOUR_ORGANIZATION_ID]
export TOPIC_ID=[YOUR_TOPIC_ID]
export SINK_NAME=[YOUR_SINK_NAME]

gcloud pubsub topics create $TOPIC_ID --project $PROJECT_ID
gcloud logging sinks create $SINK_NAME pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/$PROJECT_ID/topics/$TOPIC_ID --organization $ORGANIZATION_ID --log-filter 'logName="organizations/$ORGANIZATION_ID/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity" AND protoPayload.methodName="CreateProject" AND protoPayload."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog" AND resource.type="project"'
```

After creating the sink, gcloud will warn you to grant Pub/Sub publisher role to service account which it will use.

```
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding $ORGANIZATION_ID --member=serviceAccount:[xxxxxxxxxx]@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role=roles/pubsub.publisher
```

After these commands, you'll see the log in the Pub/Sub topic.

Answer (score 0):

All triggers for Cloud Functions are listed in the documentation on [trigger types](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling). Project creation is not listed or implied there, so it is not a direct trigger type.

In cases like this, I'd recommend looking for a way for your own script to trigger the Cloud Function explicitly after it completes (or even after it starts) the project creation. The Cloud Function can then verify that the project creation was complete, and perform the necessary actions you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it's not really simple to set up.

First, the global process (detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging#functions_log_stackdriver-python)):

- Perform a custom log query
- Sink the logs into PubSub topic
- Trigger your function on PubSub messages

For viewing your organization log level, you can't do it in the console, you have to perform it in command line. Here an example

```
gcloud logging read --organization=YOUR_ORG_NUMBER \
  'logName:"organizations/YOUR_ORG_NUMBER/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com"
   AND timestamp>="2020-05-05T23:59:59Z"
   AND timestamp<="2020-05-07T23:59:59Z"
   AND severity= "NOTICE" 
   AND protoPayload.resourceName:"projects" 
   AND protoPayload.methodName="CreateProject"'
```

With few explanations:

- `AND severity= "NOTICE"` Here for getting only the creation in success
- `AND protoPayload.resourceName:"projects"` Here for avoiding double. You have a first entry as longrunning response and the resource name start with `organizations`. When the project is created, you have a new entry with `project`. Of course, only because I want to get the creation in success.
- `AND protoPayload.methodName="CreateProject"'` Because we also move the project into a folder and we don't care about the updateProject method, only the creation here.

Your payload look like this

```
insertId: -13v21gdcfxy
logName: organizations/YOUR_ORG_NUMBE/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
protoPayload:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog
  authenticationInfo:
    principalEmail: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    serviceAccountDelegationInfo:
    - firstPartyPrincipal:
        principalEmail: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  authorizationInfo:
  - granted: true
    permission: resourcemanager.projects.create
    resource: organizations/YOUR_ORG_NUMBE
    resourceAttributes: {}
  methodName: CreateProject
  request:
    '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloudresourcemanager.v1.CreateProjectRequest
    project:
      createTime: '2020-05-06T06:41:03.605Z'
      lifecycleState: ACTIVE
      name: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      parent:
        id: 'YOUR_ORG_NUMBE'
        type: organization
      projectId: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      projectNumber: 'NEW_PROJECT_NUMBER'
  requestMetadata:
    callerIp: 2600:1900:2001:2::19
    callerSuppliedUserAgent: google-api-python-client/1.7.4 (gzip),gzip(gfe)
    destinationAttributes: {}
    requestAttributes: {}
  resourceName: projects/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  serviceName: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  status: {}
receiveTimestamp: '2020-05-06T06:41:07.346181918Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  type: project
severity: NOTICE
timestamp: '2020-05-06T06:41:06.431Z'
```

This structure example can help you to speed up your development